# In IntelliJ IDEA, how can I detach the debugger from a tomcat server started in debug mode

Tags: debugging, tomcat, intellij-idea

I sometimes do development on an app with a OSGI managed plugin system. Often I'll be debugging the core app, and then realize I need to look deeper into one of the plugins. Since the plugins specified in the pom may differ from the actual versions installed, I'd like to detach the auto-attached debugger and attach another one from a seperate IDEA window. I can't seem to find a way to do this without restarting the app in Run mode with a jvm arg. Does IDEA provide a mechanism to do this?

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't want to run the app in run mode with `suspend=y` and connect / disconnect the debugger at will?